# fetch which option value removed recently?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, jquery-chosen

I made a function for a `select` with duplicate selection. It's working well, but as I remove any one option from that select, then my array remains same.

If I remove any option then my code will detect that particular option value so I can remove it from my `AllProductArray` array.

```js
var AllProductArray = [];

function SelectProductWisely() {
  var SelectedProduct = $('#SelectProduct').val();
  if (SelectedProduct.length !== 0) {
    AllProductArray.push(parseInt(SelectedProduct));
  }
  
  console.log({
    SelectedProduct,
    AllProductArray
  });
  $('#SelectProduct').val(0);

  $.ajax({
    url: 'API.php',
    type: 'GET',
    data: {
      ReqType: "CheckLimitPrice",
      Product: AllProductArray
    },
    success: function(response) {
      console.log(response);
      if (response < 1100) {
        console.log("done");
      } else {
        console.log("done");
        enter image description here
      }
    },
  })
}
```

[image: Select product is my select option box in console 1st array print is for all selected product and 2nd array print is after remove product from selection option box]

Comment: images show : Select product is my select option box in console 1st array print is for all selected product and 2nd array print is after remove product from selection option box

Comment: Have you tried `var AllProductArray = [];` as the first line of your `SelectProductWisely()` function?

Comment: @marcus.kreusch it make my array complete blank every time my function called

Comment: The simple solution here would be to build an array of the selected values whenever the `change` event occurs. Then you don't need to worry about manually updating the global array you maintain yourself at all - and gets rid of the need for the global variable, which is always a good thing.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan but the problem is have to select duplicate values which chosen.js not allow it thats why i make select value `$('#SelectProduct').val(0);`

Comment: I don't see how that's relevant to the solution I ssuggested?

Comment: Please edit your question and make a runnable snippet that reproduces the issue (use the toolbar button to create it).

Comment: where are you actually removing any items from the array? Your code only shows a push action, not a splice one that you would need to remove an item? if you use indexOf then you can check for an item in the array and get its index then you can splice remove that item using that index

Comment: @PatrickHume thats what i want to create. i only want to fetch recently removed option from my array with help of `$('#SelectProduct').val()`

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan can we connect via anydesk sir ?

Comment: so can you post the js for the actual drop down it self, should be a simple case of when user click the icon to remove an item you just need to get that item and remove it from the array but without knowing how your drop down i wired up hard to give a proper answer 
 ```let item = "value of item selected for removal"
  if(AllProductArray.indexOf(item) !== 1){
   AllProductArray.splice(AllProductArray.indexOf(item), 1)
  }```

Comment: @PatrickHume drop down created with chosen.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry for the late reply I was away,

THis should show you how to do what you want, if you just use the events from

https://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/options.html

You can use the change even to capture if an item is being added or removed from the select list and update your array accordingly

```js
var config = {
  '.chosen-select': {},
  '.chosen-select-deselect': {
    allow_single_deselect: true
  },
  '.chosen-select-no-single': {
    disable_search_threshold: 10
  },
  '.chosen-select-no-results': {
    no_results_text: 'Oops, nothing found!'
  },
  '.chosen-select-rtl': {
    rtl: true
  },
  '.chosen-select-width': {
    width: '95%'
  }
}
for (var selector in config) {
  $(selector).chosen(config[selector]);
}
var AllProductArray = [];
$(".chosen-select").on('change', function(evt, params) {

  if (params.selected) {
    AllProductArray.push(params.selected)
  } else if (params.deselected) {

    if (AllProductArray.indexOf(params.deselected) !== -1) {
      AllProductArray.splice(AllProductArray.indexOf(params.deselected), 1)
    }
  }
  console.log(AllProductArray);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/chosen/1.8.7/chosen.proto.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/chosen/1.8.7/chosen.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/chosen/1.8.7/chosen.jquery.min.js"></script>

<select data-placeholder="Choose a Country..." class="chosen-select" multiple="" tabindex="-1">
  <option value=""></option>
  <option value="United States">United States</option>
  <option value="United Kingdom">United Kingdom</option>
  <option value="Afghanistan">Afghanistan</option>
  <option value="Aland Islands">Aland Islands</option>
  <option value="Albania">Albania</option>
  <option value="Algeria">Algeria</option>
  <option value="American Samoa">American Samoa</option>
  <option value="Andorra">Andorra</option>
  <option value="Angola">Angola</option>
  <option value="Anguilla">Anguilla</option>
  <option value="Antarctica">Antarctica</option>
  <option value="Antigua and Barbuda">Antigua and Barbuda</option>
  <option value="Argentina">Argentina</option>
  <option value="Armenia">Armenia</option>
  <option value="Aruba">Aruba</option>
  <option value="Australia">Australia</option>
  <option value="Austria">Austria</option>
  <option value="Azerbaijan">Azerbaijan</option>
  <option value="Bahamas">Bahamas</option>
  <option value="Bahrain">Bahrain</option>
  <option value="Bangladesh">Bangladesh</option>
  <option value="Barbados">Barbados</option>
  <option value="Belarus">Belarus</option>
  <option value="Belgium">Belgium</option>
  <option value="Belize">Belize</option>
  <option value="Benin">Benin</option>
  <option value="Bermuda">Bermuda</option>
  <option value="Bhutan">Bhutan</option>
  <option value="Bolivia, Plurinational State of">Bolivia, Plurinational State of</option>
  <option value="Bonaire, Sint Eustatius and Saba">Bonaire, Sint Eustatius and Saba</option>
  <option value="Bosnia and Herzegovina">Bosnia and Herzegovina</option>
  <option value="Botswana">Botswana</option>
  <option value="Bouvet Island">Bouvet Island</option>
  <option value="Brazil">Brazil</option>
  <option value="British Indian Ocean Territory">British Indian Ocean Territory</option>
  <option value="Brunei Darussalam">Brunei Darussalam</option>
  <option value="Bulgaria">Bulgaria</option>
  <option value="Burkina Faso">Burkina Faso</option>
  <option value="Burundi">Burundi</option>
  <option value="Cambodia">Cambodia</option>
  <option value="Cameroon">Cameroon</option>
  <option value="Canada">Canada</option>
  <option value="Cape Verde">Cape Verde</option>
  <option value="Cayman Islands">Cayman Islands</option>
  <option value="Central African Republic">Central African Republic</option>
  <option value="Chad">Chad</option>
  <option value="Chile">Chile</option>
  <option value="China">China</option>
  <option value="Christmas Island">Christmas Island</option>
  <option value="Cocos (Keeling) Islands">Cocos (Keeling) Islands</option>
  <option value="Colombia">Colombia</option>
  <option value="Comoros">Comoros</option>
  <option value="Congo">Congo</option>
  <option value="Congo, The Democratic Republic of The">Congo, The Democratic Republic of The</option>
  <option value="Cook Islands">Cook Islands</option>
  <option value="Costa Rica">Costa Rica</option>
  <option value="Cote D'ivoire">Cote D'ivoire</option>
  <option value="Croatia">Croatia</option>
  <option value="Cuba">Cuba</option>
  <option value="Curacao">Curacao</option>
  <option value="Cyprus">Cyprus</option>
  <option value="Czech Republic">Czech Republic</option>
  <option value="Denmark">Denmark</option>
  <option value="Djibouti">Djibouti</option>
  <option value="Dominica">Dominica</option>
  <option value="Dominican Republic">Dominican Republic</option>
  <option value="Ecuador">Ecuador</option>
  <option value="Egypt">Egypt</option>
  <option value="El Salvador">El Salvador</option>
  <option value="Equatorial Guinea">Equatorial Guinea</option>
  <option value="Eritrea">Eritrea</option>
  <option value="Estonia">Estonia</option>
  <option value="Ethiopia">Ethiopia</option>
  <option value="Falkland Islands (Malvinas)">Falkland Islands (Malvinas)</option>
  <option value="Faroe Islands">Faroe Islands</option>
  <option value="Fiji">Fiji</option>
  <option value="Finland">Finland</option>
  <option value="France">France</option>
  <option value="French Guiana">French Guiana</option>
  <option value="French Polynesia">French Polynesia</option>
  <option value="French Southern Territories">French Southern Territories</option>
  <option value="Gabon">Gabon</option>
  <option value="Gambia">Gambia</option>
  <option value="Georgia">Georgia</option>
  <option value="Germany">Germany</option>
  <option value="Ghana">Ghana</option>
  <option value="Gibraltar">Gibraltar</option>
  <option value="Greece">Greece</option>
  <option value="Greenland">Greenland</option>
  <option value="Grenada">Grenada</option>
  <option value="Guadeloupe">Guadeloupe</option>
  <option value="Guam">Guam</option>
  <option value="Guatemala">Guatemala</option>
  <option value="Guernsey">Guernsey</option>
  <option value="Guinea">Guinea</option>
  <option value="Guinea-bissau">Guinea-bissau</option>
  <option value="Guyana">Guyana</option>
  <option value="Haiti">Haiti</option>
  <option value="Heard Island and Mcdonald Islands">Heard Island and Mcdonald Islands</option>
  <option value="Holy See (Vatican City State)">Holy See (Vatican City State)</option>
  <option value="Honduras">Honduras</option>
  <option value="Hong Kong">Hong Kong</option>
  <option value="Hungary">Hungary</option>
  <option value="Iceland">Iceland</option>
  <option value="India">India</option>
  <option value="Indonesia">Indonesia</option>
  <option value="Iran, Islamic Republic of">Iran, Islamic Republic of</option>
  <option value="Iraq">Iraq</option>
  <option value="Ireland">Ireland</option>
  <option value="Isle of Man">Isle of Man</option>
  <option value="Israel">Israel</option>
  <option value="Italy">Italy</option>
  <option value="Jamaica">Jamaica</option>
  <option value="Japan">Japan</option>
  <option value="Jersey">Jersey</option>
  <option value="Jordan">Jordan</option>
  <option value="Kazakhstan">Kazakhstan</option>
  <option value="Kenya">Kenya</option>
  <option value="Kiribati">Kiribati</option>
  <option value="Korea, Democratic People's Republic of">Korea, Democratic People's Republic of</option>
  <option value="Korea, Republic of">Korea, Republic of</option>
  <option value="Kuwait">Kuwait</option>
  <option value="Kyrgyzstan">Kyrgyzstan</option>
  <option value="Lao People's Democratic Republic">Lao People's Democratic Republic</option>
  <option value="Latvia">Latvia</option>
  <option value="Lebanon">Lebanon</option>
  <option value="Lesotho">Lesotho</option>
  <option value="Liberia">Liberia</option>
  <option value="Libya">Libya</option>
  <option value="Liechtenstein">Liechtenstein</option>
  <option value="Lithuania">Lithuania</option>
  <option value="Luxembourg">Luxembourg</option>
  <option value="Macao">Macao</option>
  <option value="Macedonia, The Former Yugoslav Republic of">Macedonia, The Former Yugoslav Republic of</option>
  <option value="Madagascar">Madagascar</option>
  <option value="Malawi">Malawi</option>
  <option value="Malaysia">Malaysia</option>
  <option value="Maldives">Maldives</option>
  <option value="Mali">Mali</option>
  <option value="Malta">Malta</option>
  <option value="Marshall Islands">Marshall Islands</option>
  <option value="Martinique">Martinique</option>
  <option value="Mauritania">Mauritania</option>
  <option value="Mauritius">Mauritius</option>
  <option value="Mayotte">Mayotte</option>
  <option value="Mexico">Mexico</option>
  <option value="Micronesia, Federated States of">Micronesia, Federated States of</option>
  <option value="Moldova, Republic of">Moldova, Republic of</option>
  <option value="Monaco">Monaco</option>
  <option value="Mongolia">Mongolia</option>
  <option value="Montenegro">Montenegro</option>
  <option value="Montserrat">Montserrat</option>
  <option value="Morocco">Morocco</option>
  <option value="Mozambique">Mozambique</option>
  <option value="Myanmar">Myanmar</option>
  <option value="Namibia">Namibia</option>
  <option value="Nauru">Nauru</option>
  <option value="Nepal">Nepal</option>
  <option value="Netherlands">Netherlands</option>
  <option value="New Caledonia">New Caledonia</option>
  <option value="New Zealand">New Zealand</option>
  <option value="Nicaragua">Nicaragua</option>
  <option value="Niger">Niger</option>
  <option value="Nigeria">Nigeria</option>
  <option value="Niue">Niue</option>
  <option value="Norfolk Island">Norfolk Island</option>
  <option value="Northern Mariana Islands">Northern Mariana Islands</option>
  <option value="Norway">Norway</option>
  <option value="Oman">Oman</option>
  <option value="Pakistan">Pakistan</option>
  <option value="Palau">Palau</option>
  <option value="Palestinian Territory, Occupied">Palestinian Territory, Occupied</option>
  <option value="Panama">Panama</option>
  <option value="Papua New Guinea">Papua New Guinea</option>
  <option value="Paraguay">Paraguay</option>
  <option value="Peru">Peru</option>
  <option value="Philippines">Philippines</option>
  <option value="Pitcairn">Pitcairn</option>
  <option value="Poland">Poland</option>
  <option value="Portugal">Portugal</option>
  <option value="Puerto Rico">Puerto Rico</option>
  <option value="Qatar">Qatar</option>
  <option value="Reunion">Reunion</option>
  <option value="Romania">Romania</option>
  <option value="Russian Federation">Russian Federation</option>
  <option value="Rwanda">Rwanda</option>
  <option value="Saint Barthelemy">Saint Barthelemy</option>
  <option value="Saint Helena, Ascension and Tristan da Cunha">Saint Helena, Ascension and Tristan da Cunha</option>
  <option value="Saint Kitts and Nevis">Saint Kitts and Nevis</option>
  <option value="Saint Lucia">Saint Lucia</option>
  <option value="Saint Martin (French part)">Saint Martin (French part)</option>
  <option value="Saint Pierre and Miquelon">Saint Pierre and Miquelon</option>
  <option value="Saint Vincent and The Grenadines">Saint Vincent and The Grenadines</option>
  <option value="Samoa">Samoa</option>
  <option value="San Marino">San Marino</option>
  <option value="Sao Tome and Principe">Sao Tome and Principe</option>
  <option value="Saudi Arabia">Saudi Arabia</option>
  <option value="Senegal">Senegal</option>
  <option value="Serbia">Serbia</option>
  <option value="Seychelles">Seychelles</option>
  <option value="Sierra Leone">Sierra Leone</option>
  <option value="Singapore">Singapore</option>
  <option value="Sint Maarten (Dutch part)">Sint Maarten (Dutch part)</option>
  <option value="Slovakia">Slovakia</option>
  <option value="Slovenia">Slovenia</option>
  <option value="Solomon Islands">Solomon Islands</option>
  <option value="Somalia">Somalia</option>
  <option value="South Africa">South Africa</option>
  <option value="South Georgia and The South Sandwich Islands">South Georgia and The South Sandwich Islands</option>
  <option value="South Sudan">South Sudan</option>
  <option value="Spain">Spain</option>
  <option value="Sri Lanka">Sri Lanka</option>
  <option value="Sudan">Sudan</option>
  <option value="Suriname">Suriname</option>
  <option value="Svalbard and Jan Mayen">Svalbard and Jan Mayen</option>
  <option value="Swaziland">Swaziland</option>
  <option value="Sweden">Sweden</option>
  <option value="Switzerland">Switzerland</option>
  <option value="Syrian Arab Republic">Syrian Arab Republic</option>
  <option value="Taiwan, Province of China">Taiwan, Province of China</option>
  <option value="Tajikistan">Tajikistan</option>
  <option value="Tanzania, United Republic of">Tanzania, United Republic of</option>
  <option value="Thailand">Thailand</option>
  <option value="Timor-leste">Timor-leste</option>
  <option value="Togo">Togo</option>
  <option value="Tokelau">Tokelau</option>
  <option value="Tonga">Tonga</option>
  <option value="Trinidad and Tobago">Trinidad and Tobago</option>
  <option value="Tunisia">Tunisia</option>
  <option value="Turkey">Turkey</option>
  <option value="Turkmenistan">Turkmenistan</option>
  <option value="Turks and Caicos Islands">Turks and Caicos Islands</option>
  <option value="Tuvalu">Tuvalu</option>
  <option value="Uganda">Uganda</option>
  <option value="Ukraine">Ukraine</option>
  <option value="United Arab Emirates">United Arab Emirates</option>
  <option value="United Kingdom">United Kingdom</option>
  <option value="United States">United States</option>
  <option value="United States Minor Outlying Islands">United States Minor Outlying Islands</option>
  <option value="Uruguay">Uruguay</option>
  <option value="Uzbekistan">Uzbekistan</option>
  <option value="Vanuatu">Vanuatu</option>
  <option value="Venezuela, Bolivarian Republic of">Venezuela, Bolivarian Republic of</option>
  <option value="Viet Nam">Viet Nam</option>
  <option value="Virgin Islands, British">Virgin Islands, British</option>
  <option value="Virgin Islands, U.S.">Virgin Islands, U.S.</option>
  <option value="Wallis and Futuna">Wallis and Futuna</option>
  <option value="Western Sahara">Western Sahara</option>
  <option value="Yemen">Yemen</option>
  <option value="Zambia">Zambia</option>
  <option value="Zimbabwe">Zimbabwe</option>
</select>
```

I hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

images show : Select product is my select option box in console 1st array print is for all selected product and 2nd array print is after remove product from selection option box